# On Ubuntu, why "sudo apt-get" sometimes and "sudo aptitude" other times?

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to figure out how to install libgtk2.0-dev and found that I have to use

```
sudo aptitude install
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install
```

Why these two different ways of getting stuff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`apt-get` and `aptitude` are both frontends to dpkg. Use one or the other but be consistent. Aptitude is newer and is suppose to be easier to use. It also unifies some of the `apt-*` functions. You can use `aptitude` to search *and* install while with apt-* you need `apt-get` and `apt-cache` for installation and searching respectively.

I usually replace all `apt-get` examples with `aptitude` when copying & pasting commands.

Run `aptitude` without any options to get an interface for selecting packages. I don't ever use it so I don't know how friendly it is.

Answer (score 3):

[**apt-get**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) and [**aptitude**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29) are both interfaces to [**dpkg**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg), the Debian package manager.

**aptitude** came later than the **apt-** suite of commands and has some usability features not present in the latter, but I have yet to come across a case where you *have* to use one over the other.

The Wikipedia entry for **aptitude** states that it started out as a front-end to the **apt-** suite:

> **aptitude** is a front-end to the Advanced Packaging Tool (APT). It displays a list of software packages and allows the user to interactively pick packages to install or remove. [...] *Even though aptitude is a single executable, it provides CLI functionality similar to that of apt- family of tools (apt-get, apt-cache, apt-listchanges, etc).* Aptitude also emulates most apt-get command line options, allowing it to act as a drop-in replacement for some of the apt-get usages.

Answer (score 2):

Long-time Debian users have told me elsewhere that `aptitude` has it's own database that it maintains alongside the one that `apt` keeps. This means that using both interchangabley will result in some confusing things happening sometimes, particularly in `aptitude` when it seems to have a slightly stale copy of the package state. I have seen this happen: it results in things like packages you mysteriously can't remove or can't install.

The GUI program `synaptic` doesn't have this problem because it relies entirely on the `apt` database.

Answer (score 1):

Aptitude and apt-get serve the exact same purpose for Ubuntu Dapper and beyond.  Prior to that, apt-get might not auto-remove things as it should.

Source: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/aptitude

Answer (score 0):

One of the minor differences is that if you have packages marked for 'auto removal' that while a simple apt-get install  will list them, an aptitude install  will go ahead and remove them as part of the package install.

Not a big deal unless you install packages with 'build-dep', starting in 8.10 all build-dep installed packages are marked as auto installed (will be added to auto remove in apt-get and removed in aptitude.

(if you plan on building and using 'build-dep' then this prevents the auto marking if you wish to keep (and or prevent a large auto remove list in apt-get
Ex. mplayer
sudo apt-get build-dep mplayer -o APT::Get::Build-Dep-Automatic=false