# If aptitude is more preferable then why does bash advise apt-get?

Tags: aptitude, apt-get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Ubuntu, why "sudo apt-get" sometimes and "sudo aptitude" other times?](https://superuser.com/questions/42967/on-ubuntu-why-sudo-apt-get-sometimes-and-sudo-aptitude-other-times)

In the documentation it is said that aptitude is more preferable command to manage packets. If it's so why does bash advice apt-get?
For example I'm trying to launch Midnight Commander which I don't have on ubuntu. The reply is "The program 'mc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install mc"?

Comment: What documentation are you specifically talking about? What is the actual problem that you are experiencing? More preferable just means that it might be easier for users to use the CLI than to run everything in a pure command-line way...

Comment: Just as a reference, aptitude is just an nCurses frontend for apt-get.